# Can't log into my computer after video cart update

Tags: log

This morning I tried to update my video card, my computer has 8gb of ram, i7-2600k, and a gtx750ti.  I am rather new to ubuntu, I can't log in using Ctrl alt f1 sadly, I just get a log in error. All I see when I log in is this: [image]

Here is a link to the down arrow, sorry about the toy I have in the backgroundDown arrow :D: http://youtu.be/yfub9V9op5g

[image]
[image]
These are the only fails I see.

Answer (score 1):

From whatever you have described here it seems that your Ubuntu is not correctly starting up. There is some process in the init.d that is getting stuck. You need to investigate that. Why don't you press the down key while Ubuntu is starting up. Instead of showing you the graphics it will show you the actual services as they get loaded. Watching your services getting loaded up will give you a pretty good idea as to what is failing. Find that out and update your question.